# Multiple version of jQuery autocomplete on same page

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I need to have two autocomplete box as a part of my current requirement. It already had normal autocomplete box which was previously implemented with autocomplete version 1.0.2, Now i have implemented another autocomplete box with auto-complete UI Version 1.8.16. So necessity is multiple version of jQuery autocomplete need to run on same page which is causing conflict kind of issue.Ofcourse, previously implemented autocomplete box cannot be redone or upgraded.

Issue: Autocomplete 1 (implemented with 1.0.2) works only when i comment the autocomplete plugin 1.8.16

I want to make both the functions work.

Could you please advise what can be done on this?

Any leads would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you not have the second based off 1.0.2 also ??

Comment: Doing this is not a good idea.  It really shouldn't be much work to get your old autocomplete working with the newest version of jQuery UI (1.8.20 btw).

Comment: This is a duplicate of several other of your questions. Please do not ask duplicate questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autocomplete UI 1.8.16 and Autocomplete 1.0.2 plugin issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794341/autocomplete-ui-1-8-16-and-autocomplete-1-0-2-plugin-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to answer this because I'm not 100% certain, but I'm pretty sure that two versions of a plugin can't coexist in the same jQuery instance as long as they have the same name (e.g. `$.autocomplete`). But you can work around the issue. Here are a few examples, sorted by how much I recommend them:

- Upgrade the old autoComplete implementation to use version 1.8
- Just use the old version of autoComplete for your new implementation
- Manually edit the name of the newer version of the plugin to something like autocomplete2. Either do this manually or between plugin includes (see below)
- Use two separate instances of jQuery on the same page, loading each autoComplete plugin version into each respective jQuery instance. You can do this by calling [**`jQuery.noConflict`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) after loading each jQuery version and storing them in separate variables, e.g. `window.$` and `window.$2`

---

Renaming versions dynamically (Grabbed from Samuel Rossille's answer, edited to not break the old autocomplete implementation)

```
<!-- First include the new autocomplete plugin (1.8) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/autocomplete version 1.8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Then 'rename' the plugin to something else, e.g. autocomplete18
    jQuery.fn.autocomplete18 = jQuery.fn.autocomplete;
</script>
<!-- Then include the old version, which will overwrite jQuery.autocomplete -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/autocomplete version 1.0"></script>

<script>
    // $.autocomplete18 should now contain the new autocomplete version
    // $.autocomplete should contain the old version, not breaking the previous
    // implementation
</script>
```

Comment: Any changes needs to be done on the plugin side? Like renaming of function names?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the above code the plugin is renamed from `autocomplete` to `autocomplete18` before `autocomplete` is overwritten by the old plugin. There is, however, no need to edit the code of the plugin, unless you'd prefer to do that **instead** of renaming it dynamically